When does $[F] \cdot [\mathcal O_Y] = [F|_Y]$ hold in $K^0$?
$\DeclareMathOperator{\Coh}{Coh}$Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over $\mathbb C$, and let $S$ be any scheme over $\mathbb C$. Suppose $F \in \Coh(X \times S)$ is a flat family of sheaves on $X$, parametrized by $S$ (i.e. $F$ is flat with respect to the projection map $q:X \times S \to S$). Then it is known[1, Prop. 2.1.10] that the class $[F] \in K_0(X \times S)$ actually belongs to $K^0(X \times S)$, because it admits a finite locally free resolution. Pick a closed point $x \in X$, and consider in $K^0(X \times S)$ the product
$$ [F] \cdot p^* [\mathcal O_x] = [F] \cdot [\mathcal O_{\{x\} \times S}].$$
The equality holds true since $p$ is a flat morphism, so pulling-back a locally free resolution of $\mathcal O_x$ gives a resolution of $\mathcal O_{\{x\} \times S}$. Now in [1, Example 8.1.8 ii)], they seem to claim
$$[F] \cdot p^* [\mathcal O_x] = [F|_{\{x\} \times S}],$$
and I have no clue why that would be true. If I resolve $F$
$$0 \to F_n \to \dotsc \to F_0 \to F \to 0$$
by locally free sheaves $F_i$,
then why is taking the tensor product with $\mathcal O_{\{x\}\times S}$ exact?

[1] Huybrechts, Lehn; The Geometry of Moduli Spaces of Sheaves

This is definitely not true in general. For instance, if you take $F = p^*\mathcal{O}_x$ then the left side is
$$
\sum (-1)^i[\wedge^iT_{x}^\vee X \otimes p^*\mathcal{O}_x] = 0,
$$
while the right side is just $[p^*\mathcal{O}_x] \ne 0$.
